# How do I override div style:background-color with class?

Tags: html, css

This is how the div currently looks like

```
<div class="toolbar" style="box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232); height: 56px; padding: 0px 24px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;"><div class="toolbar" style="position: relative; margin-left: -24px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;"><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 15px; height: 48px; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; outline: none; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54); margin-right: 24px; flex: 1 1 0%; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;"><div style="cursor: pointer; height: 100%; position: relative; width: 100%;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; content: &quot; &quot;; display: table;"></div><div style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 56px; line-height: 56px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; position: relative; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 56px; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">ALL CLIENTS</div><button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 12px; outline: none; font-size: 0px; font-weight: inherit; position: absolute; z-index: 1; overflow: visible; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; width: 48px; height: 48px; fill: rgb(224, 224, 224); right: 16px; top: 4px; background: none;"><div><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: inherit; height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg></div></button><div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); bottom: 1px; left: 0px; margin: -1px 24px; right: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;"></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; content: &quot; &quot;; clear: both; display: table;"></div></div><div style="display: none;"><!-- react-empty: 25 --><!-- react-empty: 26 --></div></div></div><div class="toolbar" style="position: relative; margin-left: -24px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;"><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 15px; height: 48px; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; outline: none; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54); margin-right: 24px; flex: 1 1 0%; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;"><div style="cursor: pointer; height: 100%; position: relative; width: 100%;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; content: &quot; &quot;; display: table;"></div><div style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 56px; line-height: 56px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; position: relative; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 56px; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">ALL VERTICALS</div><button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 12px; outline: none; font-size: 0px; font-weight: inherit; position: absolute; z-index: 1; overflow: visible; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; width: 48px; height: 48px; fill: rgb(224, 224, 224); right: 16px; top: 4px; background: none;"><div><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: inherit; height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg></div></button><div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); bottom: 1px; left: 0px; margin: -1px 24px; right: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;"></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; content: &quot; &quot;; clear: both; display: table;"></div></div><div style="display: none;"><!-- react-empty: 39 --><!-- react-empty: 40 --></div></div></div><div class="toolbar" style="position: relative; margin-left: -24px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;"><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 15px; height: 48px; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; outline: none; position: relative; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54); margin-right: 24px; flex: 1 1 0%; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;"><div style="cursor: pointer; height: 100%; position: relative; width: 100%;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; content: &quot; &quot;; display: table;"></div><div style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); height: 56px; line-height: 56px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1; position: relative; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 56px; text-overflow: ellipsis; top: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">ALL INSTANCES</div><button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 12px; outline: none; font-size: 0px; font-weight: inherit; position: absolute; z-index: 1; overflow: visible; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; width: 48px; height: 48px; fill: rgb(224, 224, 224); right: 16px; top: 4px; background: none;"><div><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); fill: inherit; height: 24px; width: 24px; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg></div></button><div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); bottom: 1px; left: 0px; margin: -1px 24px; right: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;"></div><div style="box-sizing: border-box; content: &quot; &quot;; clear: both; display: table;"></div></div><div style="display: none;"><!-- react-empty: 53 --><!-- react-empty: 54 --></div></div></div></div>
```

As you can see the `style` attribute puts a `background-color` property as

```
style="box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
```

However, I wanted a different color and I can not change this `div` directly, so I added a `CSS class` called `toolbar` that looks like

```
.toolbar {
    background-color: #37517e;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Which can be seen from the `div` code above. However, the background-color from `.toolbar` is ignored and the one from `style` is applied. I confirmed this in `DevTools`

[image]

How can I apply the color of my choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

used `!important` in css property

```
.toolbar {
    background-color: #37517e!important;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```css
.rowTest{
 background-color:pink!important;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:green;width:100%;height:50px;" class="rowTest"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to override inline `style` attribute using `class` is with the [`!important` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#How_to_override_!important):

```
.toolbar {
    background-color: #37517e !important;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```css
div.cls {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="color: red;" class="cls">This text should be red, but it's not</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `!important` tag. This overrides other CSS rules that may apply. That said -- having a bunch of styling in the `style` tag in your HTML is discouraged. I'd add this information to your stylesheet and associate it with the div and class. This allows you to better visualize the cascading nature of the rules... the latest rule applies to an element.